# NetworkComms custom object error - "objectToSerialize must implement IExplicitlySerialize"

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net, networkcomms.net

I get this error from the SendObject method when I try to serialize an object just as the NetworkComms example says to do it. This seems like something silly, but I can't figure out what I need to do, and I don't think implementing the IExplicitlySerialize interface is the answer. Here is my calling method and the serialized class:

```
public static void SendTestPacket()
        {
            var message = "This is a test packet";
            NetworkComms.SendObject("PacketPrintToConsole", "192.168.1.105", 5614, new PacketPrintToConsole(message));
        }


    [ProtoContract]
    public class PacketPrintToConsole
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Message { get; set; }


        public PacketPrintToConsole() { }

        public PacketPrintToConsole(string message)
        {
            this.Message = message;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same

Comment: No, I have not. It's kind of ridiculous how bad the documentation is. If you find one, I'd love to hear the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you already figured it out, but for everyone else finding this here (like me). Here´s the answer.

That error message tells you, that you have to define a serializer.
You have an object you want to send, but you didn´t tell NetworkComms what serializer to use.
So you can either implement IExplicitlySerialize in your object or use a serializer that has already been created for protobuf-net.

You need to use the **NetworkCommsDotNet.DPSBase.ProtobufSerializer**.
You have to reference the ProtobufSerializer.dll compiled from the NetworkComms source you can get on github and then define the SendReceiveOptions.

Example:

```cs
SendReceiveOptions customSendReceiveOptions = new SendReceiveOptions<ProtobufSerializer>();
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("192.168.1.105", 5614);
TCPConnection serverConnection = TCPConnection.GetConnection(connectionInfo, customSendReceiveOptions);

var message = "This is a test packet";
serverConnection.SendObject("PacketPrintToConsole", new PacketPrintToConsole(message));
```

This has only to be done where the object will be serialized to be sent.
A receiving client just need´s to have protobuf-net with the same object class to deserialize into.

Example with SendReceiveObject to request a message.

```
SendReceiveOptions customSendReceiveOptions = new SendReceiveOptions<ProtobufSerializer>();
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<int>("GetMessage", GetMessageRequest, customSendReceiveOptions);
```

The method to send the result:

```
private static void GetMessageRequest(PacketHeader packetheader, Connection connection, int incomingobject)
{
    connection.SendObject("MessageReply", new MessageObject(message));
}
```

And on the client side then:

```
ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("192.168.2.105", 5614);
TCPConnection serverConnection = TCPConnection.GetConnection(connectionInfo);
MessageObject myMessageObject = serverConnection.SendReceiveObject<ImageWrap>("GetMessage", "MessageReply", 1000);

if (myMessageObject != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myMessageObject.Message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, new to this language and was really struggling to make sense of this but your answer cleared things up!